# pdfHTML not honoring CSS styles

Tags: html, css, itext7, pdfhtml

Is there a list of CSS styles that pdfHTML supports? Their site says "It supports the parts of the HTML 5 and CSS 3 specification that apply in a PDF context" which makes sense (e.g. no reason to support CSS animations).

However, I am having an issue with what I would think is some simple styling that would apply to PDFs.

One problem is the following style is not being applied to images:

```
img { max-width: 100%; }
```

I have a few images where their widths are physically bigger than the page so the images are getting cut off. I am not able to change the source HTML nor am I able to shrink the image files. What is the best practice to getting images to behave?

Another problem has to do with table styles. These aren't being applied:

```
table { vertical-align: top; }
tr:nth-child(even) { background: #eee; }
```

Like the images problem, these style look fine in a browser. What's the recommended way to format tables?

Thanks

Comment: `nth-child` will be supported in the next release of `pdfHTML`. It is already supported in the current development snapshot version.

Comment: @AlexeySubach: Cool. Any thoughts on the image width? That's the killer right now. If I can get the images to sit on the page I think we should be able to move forward with using itext.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`max-width` CSS property is not supported yet in `pdfHTML`. You can try to work around that problem using your own custom CSS applier for images and reset width to whatever you want if some conditions are met.

First, create the CSS applier for images:

```
final ICssApplier customImageCssApplier = new BlockCssApplier() {
    @Override
    public void apply(ProcessorContext context, IStylesContainer stylesContainer, ITagWorker tagWorker) {
        super.apply(context, stylesContainer, tagWorker);
        if (tagWorker.getElementResult() instanceof Image) {
            Image img = (Image) tagWorker.getElementResult();
            if (img.getImageWidth() > 500) {
                img.setWidth(UnitValue.createPercentValue(100));
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Then, make sure this applier is retrieved in the factory. To do this, you will have to override `getCustomCssApplier`:

```
ICssApplierFactory cssApplierFactory = new DefaultCssApplierFactory() {
    @Override
    public ICssApplier getCustomCssApplier(IElementNode tag) {
        if (TagConstants.IMG.equals(tag.name())) {
            return customImageCssApplier;
        }
        return super.getCustomCssApplier(tag);
    }
};
```

Finally, create `ConverterProperties` and make sure to pass it to `HtmlConverter.convertToPdf`:

```
ConverterProperties properties = new ConverterProperties().setCssApplierFactory(cssApplierFactory);
```

Comment: This is a dirty workaround, though, that might not work in tricky cases.You may play around with the size of physical image that will trigger your logic (`500` in my example) and with the size of the image you set for it (you might want to try both with percent and point value). Please make sure to communicate your problems to the sales team if you still aren't able to solve them.

Comment: I'm writing this in C#. Is the top line in your two blocks similar to: public class CustomImageCssApplier : BlockCssApplier...and then the method would be: public override void Apply(blahblah)?

Comment: I think this works for us, thank you. I will put in my request that image formatting from css be added when possible. Until then, I look forward to the table formatting which will be some sweet icing on the cake..

Comment: Generally speaking, you can download the latest snapshot versions at [artifactory](https://repo.itextsupport.com/webapp/#/artifacts/browse/tree/General/nuget), but the `nth-child` functionality hasn't been ported to C# yet. You can come back in a few days and download `itext7.pdfhtml.1.0.1-SNAPSHOT.nupkg`. Make sure to also download latest snapshot of Core: `itext7.7.0.3-SNAPSHOT.nupkg`. But I believe the new release of `iText` will be done in a matter of roughly a month, so you can wait for a new release as well if it works for you.